# d3 angular 2 pie chart d3.arc type error

Tags: angular, d3.js, typescript

I get this error: *'PieArcDatum' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefaultArcObject.'* at this line of code Argument of type 
 *return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";* Please help!

Everything works apart from the labeling which this code should accomplish.

Running angular 2 with the cli interface (webpack).

Please see code below.

```
let element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

// finds the width
this.width = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
this.height = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

// gets the html object for d3 to manipuluate
let svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
  .attr('width', this.width)
  .attr('height', this.height);

// creates the pie chart object
var pieChart = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")");

// finds the maximum width or height - whichever is smallest
var radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2;

// creates the information to create the pie chart circle
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(radius);

// creates a function to read in data and deduce the correct angles
let pie = d3.pie<Datum>().sort(null).value((d: Datum):number => d.quantity);

// uses the pie function to work out the correct angles for the pie chart
var piedata = pie(this.data);


// used to edit the pie chart colours
var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

//uses the arc and pie data functions to create the pie chart
pieChart.selectAll("path")
  .data(piedata)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",  <any>arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return colour(d.data.category);
      });
  ;

  var labelArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var selection = pieChart.selectAll("text").data(piedata);
selection.enter().append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.category; });
```

}

Comment: Just to add, i'm using d3 v4 and Datum is the following interface:

Comment: interface Datum {
    category: string;
    quantity: number;
}

Comment: Also everything works apart (i.e if I take it out the piechart will display albeit without labels) from:                selection.enter().append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.category; });

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, explicitly cast the radius as a number and used an array of numbers for the data instead of the the Datum datatype. The code now reads as

```
private data: Array<number>;
```

and

```
var radius:number = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2;
```

and

```
var labelArc = d3.arc()
.innerRadius(radius-40)
.outerRadius(radius);

this.pieChart.selectAll("text").data(piedata).enter().append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value});
```